# Routing Strategies In Angular 2.0. Can i mantain my own history stack?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

i have a peculiar situation in Angular 2.0 with routing

1. I don't want to repeat a navigation. i.e if a user goes to page a -> then goes to page b-> then again goes to page a-> then goes to page c and when the user presses back button,  the user should be redirected to page b and not page a. 
   What i want to achieve is Pressing the back button multiple times should not display the same page more than once.
   So if i do a>b>c>a>c>b>a>c>b>a and then start pressing back : pages a,b,c should come only once & not based on regular browser behavior.
2. On successful login, if i press back button, the login screen shouldn't come, rather it should exit or something like a blank URL and not the login URL.

Any suggestions how to implement this ?

Should i use `NavigationStart/NavigationEnd` & write my logic there ?

Comment: Could you clarify this?  In bullet point 1, I don't understand "... the user should be redirected to page b and not page a". And bullet point 2, you want to exit the app if the back button is hit?

Comment: @ppovoski sure, i meant , when i press the back button, all the pages should be seen exactly once, so on press of back button page a shouldn't open more than once on browser back button,
In second point i meant : if i have logged in successfully & then press browser back button, then it shoulnt go back to login., it should be no URL in browser or kind of exitting.

Comment: First, add the clarifications to the question, it will help everyone else as well.  Second, to be clear, if you go to pageA, then pageB, then pageA, then pageC... then start hitting back, what do you expect to happen?

Comment: @ppovoski : what i want is Pressing the back  multiple times should not display the same page more than once, if i go with default browswer behaviour then i will get Page A twice, which i dont want. !

Comment: If you go A > B > A > C, then hit back, what is your reasoning for going to B and not A?  Simply because A was hit earlier in the chain?  So if you go A > B > A > C > A > C, then hit back it should go to B?  I would like to see the use case for this.

Comment: The usecase is Pressing the back button multiple times should not display the same page more than once, the same code needs to be run on mobile too, so whatever o/p Angular 2 Gives, i also keep it on a mobile build, A user may not frequently hit browser back button, but a user definitely will hit back button on an android Device.
And need was that app has to be in Angular 2 not Ionic And not NativeScript, as it can be leveraged in web too.
So if i do a>b>a>c>b>a>c
then start doing back 
a should come just once & Not thrice same for all.

Comment: You'll need to either override the history mechanism for ALL browsers or build a custom 'back' button history mechanism and hope the user uses it.

Comment: @ppovoski that was the question is, how can i do it in Angular 2 ? should i implement LocationStrategy & Write my own logic for all methods of Location Strategy. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/LocationStrategy-class.html & Use that ?

Comment: Yes.  You are expecting custom, non-standard behavior.  Unless someone else has already invented this, you will need to write your own logic and use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the following by writting my own LocationStrategy

```
@Injectable()
export class TestClass implements LocationStrategy {

path(includeHash?: boolean) : string{
       //write my own logic here 
    }
pushState(state: any, title: string, url: string, queryParams: string) : void{
         console.log("push state called");
        //write my own logic here
    }
}
```

And in my app.module.ts

```
  {provide:LocationStrategy,useClass:TestClass },
```

This way i was able to achieve my requirements.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a more robust example? For example how did you resolve your original questions logic since your answer here doesn't really cover the solution.

Comment: I would very much appreciate if you could update your answer with a working solution that others (including me) could benefit from.